# Working with Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, macos, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

I am trying out the Visual Studio Code editor.  I have it installed on my MacBook Pro.

I have created a WebApi project and can get it to run. I wish to call out to an external API but can't seem to instantiate a new WebClient object.

I get the following when running the web server.

```
DNXCore,Version=v5.0 error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'WebClient' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I have no idea how to reference it. I have tried the `using System.Net;`, as well as, `System.Net.WebClient` in my controller method.

I am sure I am missing something simple but I just don't know what I need to do with using a full fledged version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Did you add a reference to System.Net @ the project level?

Comment: @Tdorno I'm guessing no. I didn't do anything myself and I can't find any documentation on how to do that in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: You reference it in the [project.json file](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Project.json-file). Although I'm not sure if WebClient is in .NET Core. [HttpClient is](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs).